# How to write a prepared update query?

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, qt

I've been trying to write an update function that takes the user to be updated(usr), the flag which then translates to the field to be updated and the new value. Here's the function,

```
bool DBManager::updateDB(User* usr, int flag, QVariant& value)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    bool status = false;
    QString temp_value = "";
    QList<QString> fieldlist = {"First_Name", "Last_Name", "Email", "Username", "Password"};
    QString field = fieldlist.at(flag);

    if (field == "First_Name") {
        usr->setFirstName(value.toString());
        temp_value = usr->getFirstName();
    } else if (field == "Last_Name") {
        usr->setLastName(value.toString());
        temp_value = usr->getLastName();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "invalid option";
    }

    query.prepare("UPADATE Users SET :field = :newValue WHERE Username = :Username");
    query.bindValue(":field",field);
    query.bindValue(":newValue",temp_value);
    query.bindValue(":Username",usr->getUserName());
    qDebug() << query.boundValues();
    if (m_db.isOpen()){
        if (query.exec()){
            status = true;
            qDebug() << "DATABASE:: Record update successful";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "DATABASE:: Record update unsuccessful - " << query.lastError();
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "DATABASE:: not open ";
    }

    return status;
}
```

When I run the code I get an error. Here is the output:

```
QMap((":Username", QVariant(QString, "zielinkin1"))(":field", QVariant(QString, "Last_Name"))(":newValue", QVariant(QString, "Thibos")))

DATABASE:: Record update unsuccessful -  QSqlError("", "Parameter count mismatch", "") User not updated DATABASE:: database closed
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause

**First problem**

It is not hard to guess, that value binding works only for values, not for field names.

For more info, please read about [Inserting, Updating, and Deleting Records](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-sqlstatements.html#inserting-updating-and-deleting-records).

**Second problem**

Found by @JimCastro:

You have a typo in your query. `UPADATE` should be `UPDATE`.

### Solution

Use a string concatenation to form your prepared query.

### Example

1. Instead of

   ```
   query.prepare("UPDATE Users SET :field = :newValue WHERE Username = :Username");
   ```

   write

   ```
   query.prepare("UPDATE Users SET " + field + " = :newValue WHERE Username = :Username");
   ```
2. Delete or comment this line

   ```
   query.bindValue(":field",field);
   ```

Comment: wow i feel sily about the typo. After applying all corrections, the code executes fine. thank you

Comment: @Anon01011010, you are very welcome! It would be nice, if you mark the answer as accepted and/or consider upvoting it, once your reputation allows.